# How do I use CLX/XLIB from Common Lisp after installing it from my package manager?

Tags: module, lisp, common-lisp, x11, clisp

I'm trying to use CLX while learning common lisp, because I figure it's more effective to learn if I have an actual, tangible, practical result. Unfortunately, I can't get CLX to work. I followed [the first bit of this tutorial](http://www.cawtech.demon.co.uk/clx/simple/examples.html), after installing the `clisp` and `clisp-module-clx` packages in debian.

I think I'm just horribly misunderstanding clisp's package / module / etc. loading system, but I can't find any resources for how to do this.

**foo.lisp**:

```
(defun pop-up-window (life-time &optional (host ""))
  (let* ((display (xlib:open-display host))
         (screen (first (xlib:display-roots display)))
         (root-window (xlib:screen-root screen))
         (my-window (xlib:create-window
                      :parent root-window
                      :x 0
                      :y 0 
                      :width 200
                      :height 300)))
    (xlib:map-window my-window)
    (xlib:display-finish-output display)
    (format t "it should be here ~%")
    (sleep life-time)
    (xlib:destroy-window my-window)
    (xlib:close-display display)
)

(pop-up-window 10)
```

**output**: `there is no package with name "XLIB"`

**Edit:**

I tried `(require "clx")` at the start of my code, but I get `#<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked`.

Comment: That tutorial seems a bit out of date. Nowadays you should use [quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) to install libraries. I'd also recommend using SBCL on Linux (the package manager version is probably old).

Comment: @jkiiski Thanks, that's so much easier! Though, I don't like that the ql:quickload command produces a few lines of "Loading" messages at the top of my script each time it runs :/

Comment: `(ql:quickload "library" :silent t)` and there won't be any messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLX system was most likely not installed. You could download the archive yourself and configure [ASDF](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/doc/best_practices.md) to load the system, but the easiest route is to first install [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/). Then, you can execute:

```
(ql:quickload :clx)
```

This downloads, compiles and loads the desired system and all its dependencies. This step should be executed each time you restart your Lisp environment. As soon as you need more than one libraries, you should also define your own system (for example in `~/quicklisp/local-projects/`) and load that one instead.